# How to make text over an image and show it when the mouse hovers over the image?

Tags: html, css

I wanna make text over an image. I want to do something like

[image]

I wanna show this text when you hover the mouse over the image.

Here's my current HTML & CSS

```css
.moimage {
  width: 120px;
  height: 176px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.covercomment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.name {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="molist">
  <img class="moimage" src="http://i.imgur.com/UU5q8FB.jpg">
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li class="covercomment">
      <span class="cocom">2 Comments</span>
    </li>
    <li class="coverLinks">
      <span class="colin">2 Links</span>
    </li>
    <li class="coverviews">
      <span class="covedlin">60 Views</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="name">Testing Name Here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML structure**

```
<!-- Container with no position to handle flow after stack -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- Stack with position: relative -->
  <div class="stack">
    <!-- Image and overlay with position: absolute -->
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Caption -->
  <h4></h4>
</div>
```

**Width effect**

Add to `.overlay` a `width: 0`, `overflow: hidden` and a **transition** for the effect.

Make the effect happen with

```
.container:hover .overlay { width: 100% }
```

### Example

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.img-container .stack,
.img-container img,
.img-container .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-container {
  width: 120px;
  height: 176px;
}

.img-container img {
  display: block;
}

.img-container>.stack {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  color: white;
}

.img-container img,
.img-container .overlay {
  position: absolute;
}

.img-container .overlay {
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #252525;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.img-container:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container h4 {
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="stack">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/UU5q8FB.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <ul>
        <li>2 Comments</li>
        <li>2 Links</li>
        <li>60 Views</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>Name</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.moimage {
  width: 120px;
  height: 176px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.name {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="molist">
  <img class="moimage" src="http://i.imgur.com/UU5q8FB.jpg">
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li class="covercomment">
      <span class="cocom">2 Comments</span>
    </li>
    <li class="coverLinks">
      <span class="colin">2 Links</span>
    </li>
    <li class="coverviews">
      <span class="covedlin">60 Views</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="name">Testing Name Here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to make text visible when mouse is pointed to image or on 'Testing Name Here' with css 3 effect.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,body {margin:0;}
.molist {float:left; position:relative; width: 120px; height: 176px; margin:0 20px 0 0;}
.wrapper {margin:0; padding:10px;  list-style:none;}
.moimage{
width:100%;
}
.f-cntc {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); color:#fff; width:100%; height:100%; display:none;}
.molist:hover .f-cntc{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="molist">
  <img class="moimage" src="http://i.imgur.com/UU5q8FB.jpg">
  <div class="f-cntc">
 <ul class="wrapper">
   <li class="covercomment">
      <span class="cocom">2 Comments</span>
   </li>
     <li class="coverLinks">
     <span class="colin">2 Links</span>
   </li>
   <li class="coverviews">
     <span class="covedlin">60 Views</span>
   </li>
 </ul>
  </div>
 <span class="name">Testing Name Here</span>
</div> 

<div class="molist">
  <img class="moimage" src="http://i.imgur.com/UU5q8FB.jpg">
  <div class="f-cntc">
 <ul class="wrapper">
   <li class="covercomment">
      <span class="cocom">2 Comments</span>
   </li>
     <li class="coverLinks">
     <span class="colin">2 Links</span>
   </li>
   <li class="coverviews">
     <span class="covedlin">60 Views</span>
   </li>
 </ul>
  </div>
 <span class="name">Testing Name Here</span>
</div>

<div class="molist">
  <img class="moimage" src="http://i.imgur.com/UU5q8FB.jpg">
  <div class="f-cntc">
 <ul class="wrapper">
   <li class="covercomment">
      <span class="cocom">2 Comments</span>
   </li>
     <li class="coverLinks">
     <span class="colin">2 Links</span>
   </li>
   <li class="coverviews">
     <span class="covedlin">60 Views</span>
   </li>
 </ul>
  </div>
 <span class="name">Testing Name Here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can make hover with css3 effects?  Otherwise this is what i was looking for.

Comment: @Dom yes you can make css effect. check this [link](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) if my answer help don't forget to check/upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the problem, the below codes should help you achieve your objective.

```css
.moimage{
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 176px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.moimage:hover + .wrapper, .wrapper:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="molist">
  <img class="moimage" src="http://i.imgur.com/UU5q8FB.jpg">
 <ul class="wrapper">
   <li class="covercomment">
      <span class="cocom">2 Comments</span>
   </li>
     <li class="coverLinks">
     <span class="colin">2 Links</span>
   </li>
   <li class="coverviews">
     <span class="covedlin">60 Views</span>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```